# How to implement JWT authorization in addon REST Spring Atlassian Connect API?

Tags: java, jira

I created plugin using

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.atlassian.connect -DarchetypeArtifactId=atlassian-connect-spring-boot-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.5.1
```

atlassian-connect.json

```
{...
 "scopes": [
 "read", "write"
],
"authentication": {
 "type": "jwt"
 },
 "lifecycle": {
 "installed": "/installed",
 "uninstalled": "/uninstalled"
 },
 "enableLicensing": false,
 "modules": {
  "generalPages": [

  {
    "key": "comments",
    "location": "system.top.navigation.bar",
    "name": {
      "value": "Comments"
    },
    "url": "/rest/api",
    "conditions": [{
      "condition": "user_is_logged_in"
    }]
  }
]
  }
}
```

I am trying to access my API

```
 AJS.$.ajax({
                    url: "https://X.ngrok.io/rest/api",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    async: false, headers: {
    'Authorization' : "JWT {{sessionToken}}"
},
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(e);
                    },
                    error: function(response) {

                        console.log(response);
                    }
                    })
```

How to get jwt on JS side (it is better to describe

simple plugin step by step, if u could (I checked many links with examples, but…))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring an HTML page in your `atlassian-connect.json` file, i.e. the 'comments' general page. Hence, if someone opens this page, you can generate a JWT and inject it into the HTML document **before** returning it to the user/requester. Then you can use this JWT within your JavaScript code. Since you seem to be using the Spring Boot template, you should have a look at the section "Authenticating requests from iframe content back to the add-on" in the [repositories readme file](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-connect-spring-boot/src/master/). This is exactly describing your case.

The other option would be to generate a JWT based on a JWT you are receiving from the Connect application like Jira or Confluence. However, this is a bit more work to do. I can recommend to read about how to get a [a valid JWT from the Connect application within JavaScript](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/jsapi/context/) and also how the [installation handshake phase](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/authentication-for-apps/) works. Based on these you could generate your own JWT.

However, in all cases, please take care that you won't generate a new token for each request, but rather for a session, so you can use the token for multiple requests. I recommend to go with option a), because it's already supported by the Sprint Boot Connect template.